# Bool value cannot be null

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm working on an Umbraco 7 website where products are being filtered by a boolean.

- True = male
- False = women

I `Request.QueryString.Get("gender")` and recieve a `true` or `false` value that I parse into the `subPage.GetPropertyValue<bool>("gender")` which then renders out the products that is either `true` or `false`. That part works fine.

**However** if I do NOT have any `QueryStrying.Get("gender")` in the URL it returns an error that tells the `Value cannot be null.`

How do I prevent this from happening? I tried wrapping the `var genderQuery` with a 
`@if (Request.QueryString.Get("gender") != null)` but then I can't grap it from inside the `foreach`

**My code:**

```
 @if (subPages.Count() > 0)
    {
        <ul>
            @foreach (var subPage in subPages)
            {
                var genderQuery = Request.QueryString.Get("gender");

                if (subPage.Children.Count() > 0 && subPage.GetPropertyValue<bool>("gender") == bool.Parse(genderQuery))
                {
                    <li class="child @(CurrentPage.Name == subPage.Name ? currentClass :"")">

                        <a href="@subPage.Url">@subPage.Name </a>
                        <a href="@subPage.Parent.Parent.Url" class="@(CurrentPage.Name == subPage.Name ? currentClass : "hide")"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                    </li>
                }
            }
        </ul>
    }
```

Comment: Well what do you want to happen if `genderQuery` is null, i.e. it's not in the query string?

Comment: @EdPlunkett: No, `genderQuery` is a `string`, not a `bool?` at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet Derp, thanks.

Comment: "bool? gender" will accept: null, true, false. Then check if gender is null. gender.hasValue()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @if (subPages.Count() > 0)
    {
        <ul>
            @foreach (var subPage in subPages)
            {
                var genderQuery = Request.QueryString.Get("gender");

                if (subPage.Children.Count() > 0 &&
                    ( genderQuery == null || 
            subPage.GetPropertyValue<bool>("gender") == bool.Parse(genderQuery)))
                {
                    <li class="child @(CurrentPage.Name == subPage.Name ? currentClass :"")">

                        <a href="@subPage.Url">@subPage.Name </a>
                        <a href="@subPage.Parent.Parent.Url" class="@(CurrentPage.Name == subPage.Name ? currentClass : "hide")"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                    </li>
                }
            }
        </ul>
    }
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks Cetin